# GDB: How to get execution history

Tags: gcc, gdb

I am quite new to the area of compilers. I'm using gcc and I want to get execution history of a program for a particular run i.e. only those statements which are actually executed in the last run.

Is it possible with gdb? I couldn't get relevant options in gdb which could output executed statements.
Or is there any other way of obtaining execution history?

Regards,
Nikhil.

Answer (score 5):

[Process Record](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) May be what you're looking for.  The link has a quick tutorial and an overview of the functionality.

From the linked wiki page:

> Compile this program with -g, and load it into gdb, then do the
>   following:
>
> ```
>  (gdb) break main  
>  (gdb) run  
>  (gdb) record
> ```
>
> This will turn on process recording, which will now record all subsequent instructions executed by the program being debugged.
>
> Note that you can start process recording at any point (not just at
>   main). You may choose to start it later, or even earlier. The only
>   restriction is that your program has to be running (so you have to
>   type "run" before "record"). If you want to start recording from the
>   very first instruction of your program, you can do it like this:
>
> ```
>  (gdb) break _start   
>  (gdb) run   
>  (gdb) record
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set history save` command to start recording history. This can be written into the `~/.gdbinit` file. [Look at the docs](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-History.html) for more information.